# Error: Could not complete the operation due to error 8150002e

Tags: javascript, c#, vsto, outlook-addin, window.open

I am working on a Outlook VSTO add-in, in which I am using 'System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser' to display the add-in functionality.

One functional requirement is to have oauth connection to cloud accounts (like OneDrive, Dropbox). When user clicks a button (e.g. 'Connect OneDrive'), we call 'window.open' in JavaScript code (ES6) with the oauth-url.

The issue which I am facing is, if user doesn't enter any credentials and close the window, and then again try to connect the cloud account (by clicking the 'Connect OneDrive'), I am getting an exception (**Error: Could not complete the operation due to error 8150002e.**).

I couldn't find any information about the error code '8150002e' on web.

This exception is not always present but comes around 50% of the times.

Any help would be appreciated in this.

what I have tried:

1. changing the windowName param every time window.open is called
2. having global var for window Object.
3. Using _blank parameter to open a new window every time.
4. After 5-6 times, the error comes up, after 5-6 times error goes away and auth window start coming up like before.
5. Opening a simple static HTML page in 'window.open' to verify if the issue has  something to do with HTML page. The above issue is still present.
6. Resetting the System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser programmatically.
7. Removing the cookies.
8. Instead of calling window.open from JavaScript code, we call VSTO code to open the browser window, the error is still there.

**Edit**: Created a minimal viable example at 
https://github.com/vinay-x/SampleAddin

Code related to the issue:

- SDXOLForm1.cs (navigates the browser to SamplePage.HTML hosted on localhost:8001)
  SamplePage.HTML (contains a button, which calls window.open function).

The sample application has a windows form which contains a webBrowser control, which navigates to a simple HTML page which contains a button.

Comment: theres a lot of talk but no code.. Please read the [minimal viable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Does it work correctly with a standalone windows form application?

Comment: @BugFinder Thanks for the feedback. Here is the MVE https://github.com/vinay-x/SampleAddin (It is created with Addin-express). The bug is reproducible in this

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev I have create a minimal viable example at https://github.com/vinay-x/SampleAddin  
The issue is still there.
The sample application has a windows form which contains a webBrowser control, which navigates to a simple HTML page which contains a button.

Comment: Looks like you didn't notice my question. Does it work correctly with a standalone application?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Did you mean an application without webBrowser? I thought the above sample application has minimum bare bones. Would you please help me in what I am missing from your question?

Comment: I mean a regular windows form application with a web browser control.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Ohh, thanks. Yes, the error is present in a regular windows form application. However the error doesn't come always and not in every machine.

Comment: If you can reproduce the issue with a regular application you need to troubleshoot it as a non-add-in related issue. Don't you think so?

Comment: Yes, now I got to know that this is indeed non-add-in related issue. However the solution is still not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Had to deal with some IE11 stuff and I ran across this question. The solution I found to fix this issue is to set the window variable to null prior to calling window.open.

So for your example you have this:

```
function myFunction() {
    window.open("https://www.w3schools.com", 'BackfliptOAuth', "width=800,height=800,center=true,useContentSize=true");
}
```

I modified it to this:

```
var win = null;
function myFunction() {
    win = null;
    win = window.open("https://www.w3schools.com", 'BackfliptOAuth', "width=800,height=800,center=true,useContentSize=true");
}
```